# How can i exclude products from reorder function?

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, custom-options

The last orders are listed in `magento/customer/account` with an option to reorder.

How can I exclude a certain product from this particular order when reordering it?

I want this because it shouldn't be possible to **reorder** promo items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to allow orders that contain certain products to be reordered you can rewrite the method `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::_canReorder` and add your condition in there.

The method contains this loop that checks if the ordered products still exist and they are in stock.

```
foreach ($products as $productId) {
     $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
          ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
          ->load($productId);
     }
     if (!$product->getId() || (!$ignoreSalable && !$product->isSalable())) {
          return false;
     }
}
```

you can add this inside the loop just before closing it:

```
$isPromo = your logic to determine if $product is a promo product
if ($isPromo) {
    return false;
}
```

If you still want to allow reorder functionality, but don't want to add the promo products to the cart you can rewrite the method `Mage_Sales_OrderController::reorderAction` (that is actually defined in the `Mage_Sales_Controller_Abstract` class) and inside the foreach loop `foreach ($items as $item) {` add at the top of it this.

```
$isPromo = your logic here to determine if $item is a promo product
if ($isPromo) {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I simply added
`if( $item->getProductId() == 14 ){
 continue;
}`
at the beginning of the loop and it works perfektly!

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two solutions in this case.

### Solution-1 : Rewrite `Mage_Sales_OrderController`

You need to define `reorderAction` as shown beow in your rewrite controller file.

```
public function reorderAction()
{
    //product ids you want to exclude
    $excludeIds = array(); 

    if (!$this->_loadValidOrder()) {
        return;
    }
    $order = Mage::registry('current_order');

    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    $cartTruncated = false;
    /* @var $cart Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart */

    $items = $order->getItemsCollection();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        
        //skip cart updation
        if (in_array($item->getProductId(), $excludeIds)) {
            continue;
        }


        try {
            $cart->addOrderItem($item);
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e){
            if (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getUseNotice(true)) {
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addNotice($e->getMessage());
            }
            else {
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
            $this->_redirect('*/*/history');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addException($e,
                Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Cannot add the item to shopping cart.')
            );
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        }
    }

    $cart->save();
    $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
}
```

As you can see, you need to fill `$excludeIds` with your product ids which need to be excluded.

### Solution-2 : Observer Method

Use the event `controller_action_postdispatch_sales_order_reorder`. Your observer should look like this.

```
public function yourObserver($observer)
{
    //fill this array with your product ids which needs to be excluded
    $excludeIds = array(); 
    
    $checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    foreach ($checkout->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if (in_array($item->getProductId(), $excludeIds)) {
            $checkout->remove($item->getId());
        }
    }

    return $this;

}
```

Here what we do is, removing cart items based on `$excludeIds`.

Comment: nice idea with the post dispatch observer.

Comment: @Marius but if we use that, we cannot avoid addtocart action. we requires an additional cart removal. But I still believe this is the clean way of doing it since event fires only when reorder happends.

Comment: yep. I agree, the code looks cleaner even if you add some products then remove them again. I like it.